# MultiDataTrigger not working with binding path condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, custom-controls

I have implemented a WPF user control and what i want to achieve here is on mouseover on Main Grid some stack panels should hide. And i need to have multiple triggers conditions. Despite looking everywhere i am unable to find what am i doing wrong. UserControl Resources are as follow

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="StackViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid},Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FileState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Uploading" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Data binding is working fine, because when i put in a test label to check its value it was "uploading". If i remove FileState Condition it starts working. I am using it as

```
<StackPanel Name="StackViewCount" Style="{StaticResource StackViewStyle}">
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

While looking output window i found this error

> BindingExpression path error: 'FileState' property not found on 'object' ''StackPanel' (Name='StackViewCount')'. BindingExpression:Path=FileState; DataItem='StackPanel' (Name='StackViewCount'); target element is 'StackPanel' (Name='StackViewCount'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

So how can i tell the binding to look for FileState in UserControl not stackpanel

Now when i changed condition to

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FileState}" Value="Uploading" />
```

I dont see any errors but still it does not work.

Comment: FileState is a property of StackPanel?

Comment: No it is a property of UserControl. @DJ i think i am missing the point here, how could i use binding of usercontrol. As i have already tried "{Binding Path=FileState}".

Comment: Does `FileState` say `uploading` or `Uploading`? Note that case matters. Also, check the output window for errors.

Comment: Obvious i know case sensitivity matters here. Second thing you raised, give me a clue as it is searching for FileState in stack panel, which is not a stack panel proper but of parent usercontrol's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `FileState` is property of your `UserControl` and it is ancestor of `StackPanel` you have to `bind to ancestor` like:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Path=FileState, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" Value="Uploading" />
```